# prioritize in TYPO3 logicalOr database query

Tags: sql, constraints, typo3

I want to create a DB query in TYPO3. I want to distinguish between different sys_language_uids.

```
        $lanuageUid = $demand->getLanguageUid();
        if (isset($lanuageUid)) {
            $constraints['sys_language_uid'] = $query->logicalOr(
                [
                    $query->equals('sys_language_uid', 0),
                    $query->equals('sys_language_uid', $demand->getLanguageUid()),

                ]
            );
        }
```

I want a specific amount of records back, that I set with setLimit();
Lets say the recent languageUid is for spain and 0 is for english.
I want 3 records back, but I have only 2 records for spain, so I want the last record in english.
My recent query just give me the ordered records. But can I say that I want first all the spanish records and then, If they are smaller 3, I want the residual in english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with the $defaultOrderings.

```
$this->setDefaultOrderings([
    'sys_language_uid' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING
]);
```